# what does this error mean in xcode debugger window?

Tags: iphone, xcode

```
[Session started at 2009-05-28 22:36:25 +0600.]
2009-05-28 22:36:29.400 FlashCards[4440:20b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "indexView" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
2009-05-28 22:36:29.407 FlashCards[4440:20b] Stack: (
    2517688651,
    2422246971,
    2517688107,
    2517688170,
    818121900,
    816648934,
    816688492,
    816684429,
    816681688,
    817870076,
    837317240,
    837317032,
    837315376,
    837314643,
    2517182914,
    2517189668,
    2517191928,
    829005112,
    829005309,
    816175835,
    816221412,
    9384,
    9238
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that you have a UITableViewController but it's view isn't actually a UITableView. Has this the other day. Check what the class of the controller is in interface builder.

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but how can you tell that from a numeric stack trace without using atos to look up the symbols?

Comment: @Marc W - If you scroll to the right you will see the exception message.

Comment: damn, don't give away the secrets...I like the idea that people think I can read stack traces off the top of my head :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do in gdb

info symbol 9384

very useful tips on cocoawithlove :

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/debugging-tips-for-objective-c.html